# Python Turtle race game. Ending game function does not seem to work

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have got a problem with how to end my turtle python game. The code seems to function if I place the turtles at the starting/ending point from the beginning of the code, but it does not register when the turtle reaches the endpoint in gameplay. From what I know I think my maths for the end function is right. I am new and appreciate the help. I am currently offline though.

CODE:

```
import time
import turtle
from turtle import *
    
wn = turtle.Screen()
    
name=textinput("Question", "what is your name")
#display
pencolor("white")
penup()
goto(0,170)
write("hello " +name,align='center',font=('Comic Sans', 20))

#wn = turtle.screen() if the code doesn't work
#diffrent turtles here
    
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t3 = turtle.Turtle()

#starting psoition
turtle.penup()
t1.penup()
turtle.goto(-1, -230)
t1.goto(-1, -170)
#starting line postion
    

def f():
    fd(10)


def b():
    bk(10)


def l():
    left(10)

    
def r():
    right(10)


#testing
def fo():
    t1.fd(10)


def ba():
    t1.bk(10)
    

def le():
    t1.left(10)
 

def ri():
    t1.right(10)
    

#turtle coordinates
first=turtle.ycor()
second=turtle.xcor()
third=t1.ycor()
fourth=t1.xcor()
      
#when to end the game
if (turtle.ycor()>= (-160)) and (turtle.ycor()<= (-240)):
    if (turtle.xcor()>= (0)) and (turtle.xcor()<= (11)):    
        print("Finally working")
        #replaced with write who the winner is later
   
if (t1.ycor()>= (-160)) and (t1.ycor()<= (-240)):
    if (t1.xcor()>= (0)) and (t1.xcor()<= (11)):    
        print("Finally")

# onkey creates the key board = turtle.onkey("function, key")  You have to keep pressing keys for it to move
turtle.onkey(f, "w")
turtle.onkey(b, "s")
turtle.onkey(l, "a")
turtle.onkey(r, "d")
    
wn.onkey(fo, "Up")
wn.onkey(ba, "Down")
wn.onkey(le, "Left")
wn.onkey(ri, "Right")
listen()
    
#WINDOW SETUP
window = Screen()    

window.setup(800, 800)
window.title("Turtle game")
turtle.bgcolor("forestgreen")
t3.color("black")
t3.speed(0) 
t3.penup()
t3.setpos(-140, 250)
t3.write("THE TURTLE RACE", font=("Comic Sans", 30, "bold"))
t3.penup()

#turtle ask name

#add images here

#turtle controls

# def creates a function. : means opperation f means move turtle foward. fd push turtle forward

# onkey creates the key board = turtle.onkey("function, key")  You have to keep pressing keys for it to move
    
t2.speed(0)
t2.color("grey")
t2.pensize(100)
t2.penup()
t2.goto(-200, -200)
t2.left(90)
t2.pendown()
t2.forward(300)
t2.right(90)
t2.forward(500)
t2.right(90)
t2.forward(300)
t2.right(90)
t2.forward(500)
  
turtle.penup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your maths is not quite right - a coordinate can never be both <= -240 and >= -160. It should be `t.ycor() >= -240 and t.ycor() <= -160`, or more briefly, `-240 <= t.ycor() <= -160`.

Secondly, the condition as it stands is only checked once, when the code is first run. Instead, you need to get the program to check it regularly. You can do this by adding a general `onkeypress` event handler which is checked every time any key is pressed.

```
def check_status():
    for player, t in enumerate([turtle, t1]):
        if  0 <= t.xcor() <= 11 and -240 <= t.ycor() <= -160:
            print(f"Player {player} is at the endpoint")

...
wn.onkeypress(check_status)
listen()
```